# Prevent users from deleting iBooks from iPad

Tags: ios, books

I will be preparing some iBook files to use on an exhibit in a  museum, and I am afraid that visitors accidentally (or not) delete the book from the iBooks app.

I looked at the Restriction Settings, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`Settings` → `General` → scroll down → `Restrictions` → `Enable Restrictions` → create passcode and enter it again when prompted → *write it down somewhere* → toggle `Deleting Apps` to `OFF`.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it later. So by disabling *app* deletion I can also disable *content* deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, setup Guide Access on your iPad and you activate the feature to block certain parts of the App, called "blind spots." See instructions here: [How to Use Guided Access to Disable Parts of an iPad Screen](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Guided-Access-to-Disable-Parts-of-an-iPad-Screen)

I hope this helps.